# flip an image assembly code

Tags: c, qt, assembly

I'm working on a c based program that works on assembly for image twisting. Thepseudocode that is supposed to work is this one(always using images of 240x320

```
 voltearHorizontal(imgO, imgD){

    dirOrig = imgO;

    dirDest = imgD;

    dirOrig = dirOrig + 239*320; //bring the pointer to the first pixel of the last row 

    for(f=0; f<240; f++){

       for(c=0; c<320; c++){

       [dirDest]=[dirOrig];

       dirOrig++­­;

       dirDest++;

   }

   dirOrig=dirOrig+640;//move the pixel to the first one of the upper row

   }

 }
```

But when applied to assembly, on the result, the first rows are not read, leaving the space in black.

https://gyazo.com/7a76f147da96ae2bc27e109593ed6df8

this is the code I've written, that's supposed to work, and this one is what really happens to the image:

https://gyazo.com/2e389248d9959a786e736eecd3bf1531

Why are, with this code, not written/read the upper lines of pixels of the origen image to the second image? what part of code did I get wrong?

I think I have no tags left to put for my problem, thanks for any help that can be given (on where I am wrong).Also, the horitzontal flip (the oneabove is the vertical) simply finishes the program unexpectedly:

https://gyazo.com/a7a18cf10ac3c06fc73a93d9e55be70c

Comment: Do not post code as images. Always post text! I have downvoted and voted for your question to be closed because it does not contain the relevant source code (only images of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any special reason, why you write it as slow assembler?

Why don't you just keep it in fast C++? https://godbolt.org/g/2oIpzt

```
#include <cstring>

void voltearHorizontal(const unsigned char* imgO, unsigned char* imgD) {
    imgO += 239*320; //bring the pointer to the first pixel of the last row 
    for(unsigned f=0; f<240; ++f) {
      memcpy(imgD, imgO, 320);
      imgD += 320;
      imgO -= 320;
    }
}
```

Will be compiled with gcc6.3 -O3 to:

```lisp
voltearHorizontal(unsigned char const*, unsigned char*):
        lea     rax, [rdi+76480]
        lea     r8, [rdi-320]
        mov     rdx, rsi
.L2:
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rax]
        lea     rdi, [rdx+8]
        mov     rsi, rax
        sub     rax, 320
        and     rdi, -8
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdx], rcx
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rax+632]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdx+312], rcx
        mov     rcx, rdx
        add     rdx, 320
        sub     rcx, rdi
        sub     rsi, rcx
        add     ecx, 320
        shr     ecx, 3
        cmp     rax, r8
        rep movsq
        jne     .L2
        rep ret
```

Ie. like 800% more efficient than your inline asm.

---

Anyway, in your question the problem is:

```
dirOrig=dirOrig+640;//move the pixel to the first one of the upper row
```

You need to do `-= 640` to return two lines up.

About those inline asm in screens... put them as text into question, but from a quick look on them I would simply rewrite it in C++ and keep it to compiler, you are doing many performance-wrong things in your asm, so I don't see any point in doing that, plus inline asm is ugly and hard to maintain, and hard to write correctly.

---

I did check even that asm in picture. You have lines counter in `eax`, but you use `al` to copy the pixel, so it does destroy the line counter value.

Use debugger next time.

BTW, your pictures are 320x240, not 240x320.

Comment: I'm using it as a project for a teacher to check my knowledge on assembly. I'd have done it in java long ago if it weren't for that.                                                   I'll try what you have said. thanks for the answer

As for the part of using al and destroying the counter, what's the solution, changing to ebx/edx so I can use %%al freely?

Comment: @flaixman Java.. for byte manipulation, uf... ... it looks more like test from inline assembly, than assembly itself, it's bad practice to use inline assembly for such big parts of code, these should be done in separate .asm files in proper projects. And your assembly is OK for a student, but you would need like several hours of performance related lectures to get it further, while the code is technically correct (except that `al` vs `eax`), it's doing many things which are "wrong" on modern x86 CPU.

Comment: Ped7g Edit, everything worked, the problem was that I was destroying the eax counter with %%al.

really thanks for your answer, now I understand it.

It's easier for the teacher to correct one whole piece of code instead of different .asm files, and we are still on the basics, and not programming for newer CPUs because they are a little more complex than older ones.

Thanks for the help

Comment: @flaixman: About solution.. yeah, obviously either allocate registers differently (use some other for counter, or other for pixel data), but maybe you should use `rep movsd` instead (without that address-alingment advanced stuff of gcc, just naive: `ecx=320/4, esi=orig, edi=dest, rep movsd` .. => whole line copied, esi-=640, and then you can use eax as counter (eax=240 init, and dec eax + jnz).  (it will be shorter code + faster .. in lucky case, when img pointer are aligned, it will be even faster than the gcc stuff :) )